# EPERM error when serving Phonegap under Windows 10 Ubuntu Bash

Tags: cordova, phonegap-cli, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm following through the [Get Started guide](http://phonegap.com/getstarted/) for PhoneGap.

I've installed the Phonegap CLI via `yarn global add phonegap`.

I then created a new project using `phonegap create`.

Now I'm trying to run it with `phonegap serve` but immediately I get an error.

```
[phonegap] starting app server...
/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                    ^

Error: watch /mnt/d/Dev/phonegap-test/www/css/ EPERM
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1306:19)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1331:11)
    at Gaze._watchDir (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/gaze/lib/gaze.js:304:30)
    at /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/gaze/lib/gaze.js:377:10
    at iterate (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/gaze/lib/helper.js:69:5)
    at Object.forEachSeries (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/gaze/lib/helper.js:83:3)
    at Gaze._initWatched (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/gaze/lib/gaze.js:373:10)
    at Gaze.add (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/gaze/lib/gaze.js:192:8)
    at new Gaze (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/gaze/lib/gaze.js:74:10)
```

I'm using Ubuntu Bash for Windows 10. Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phonegap is trying to "watch" the folder for changes.

As of Feb 2017, *Windows 10 build 14393* Ubuntu Bash for Windows doesn't support [inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) events.

This simply won't work without a workaround.

The good news is that this is being fixed. As of Windows 10 build **14962**, the [changelog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/release_notes#build-14926) reads:

> - Inotify support for files modified through WSL. (GH #216)

This build of Windows is not yet publicly available.

As a workaround for now you can use the [Phonegap application for Windows Desktop](http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/1-install-phonegap/desktop/).